# How to add elements to a dropdown in Smarty?

Tags: php, for-loop, smarty

I'm a newbie to Smarty template engine and I got stuck at this point. Actually I want to add 1 to 31 numbers to a dropdown in a Smarty template. Below is my code:

```
<select name="date">
    {for $f = 1 to 31}
        <option value="{$foo}">{$foo}</option>
    {/for}
</select>
```

But it's giving an error. Could you please help me out of this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{section name=waistsizes start=28 loop=40 step=1}
 <option value="{$smarty.section.waistsizes.index}">
  $smarty.section.waistsizes.index}
 </option>
{/section}
```

Comment: Thanks @mrcoder. It worked for me but there is small error in your code you 've forgotten to put the curly brace on left hand side of Smarty expression.